# Is it possible to read files that are not in Google Cloud Platform from Cloud DataFlow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to read a simple CSV that is outside of the Google Cloud Platform.
Is it possible. ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet with the local CSV file:

`PCollection<String> lines = 
      p.apply(TextIO.Read.named("ReadMyFile").from("/tmp/myfile.csv"));`

[constructing-your-pipeline reading-data-into-your-pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/constructing-your-pipeline#reading-data-into-your-pipeline)

EDIT:

Based on the manual of TextIO.Read.from() it supports local files.

If you run the code on your local machine or non-GCP server, where the CSV file is, this snippet will be able to load the data into DataFlow.
[TextIO.Read.From documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/TextIO.Read)

Comment: Thanks, I'm already reading files from google cloud storage. I would like to know if I can access a file from a external location that is not GCP. Cheers

Comment: TextIO.Read.from is able to read local files. I've added more details to the answer.

Comment: @Adam Is there any reason why you mentioned `/tmp/` in your file path? I am trying to do this with Python SDK, and Dataflow workers are not recognizing my file (blank output). I tried to do this using [localfilesystem](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.23.0/apache_beam.io.localfilesystem.html) and with [textio](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.2.0/apache_beam.io.textio.html#apache_beam.io.textio.ReadFromText).

Comment: `/tmp/` is simply referencing to the temporary folder in a linux filesystem. You can use any local file path.